# Is there any method I can listen for changes to global variable to trigger an event

Tags: java, android

Android, Java. Is there any method I can listen for changes to  a global variable to trigger an event

For instance, if I create a global boolean variable called **SeeMe** in one Class. Then from a second class change the value of that global boolean to **true**.

Can the first class having listened out for this change, then execute **Tryme();**

Comment: No reason to put the major tags in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

You would implement the [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) interface in your global object, and then the [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) interface for each class that needs to receive notifications.

In your case, the variable holding `seeMe` would be in a class that's `Observable`, and the setter method for `seeMe` would call the `notify()` when the value is changed. The method `tryMe()` would be member of a class that's an `Observer`, and would receive the call to `update()` when the `Observable` is changed.

Here's a sample `Observable`:

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class GlobalValues extends Observable {

    private static GlobalValues mInstance = null;

    public static GlobalValues getInstance() {
        if( mInstance == null )
            mInstance = new GlobalValues();

        return mInstance;
    }

    public enum ValueName { NONE, SEEME, OTHERVALUE };

    static class ValueKey {
        private ValueName mValueName;

        public ValueKey( ValueName valueName ) {
            mValueName = valueName; 
        }

        public ValueName getKey() { return mValueName; }
    }



    private boolean mSeeMe = false;

    public boolean getSeeMe() { return mSeeMe; }

    public void setSeeMe( boolean value ) {
        if( value != mSeeMe ) {
            mSeeMe = value;
            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers( new ValueKey( ValueName.SEEME ) );
        }
    }

}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class SampleObserver implements Observer {

    public void startObservingGlobals() {
        GlobalValues.getInstance().addObserver( this );
    }

    public void stopObservingGlobals() {
        GlobalValues.getInstance().deleteObserver( this );
    }

    public void doTryMe( boolean newSeeMe ) {
        // do something when seeMe changes
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
        if( observable instanceof GlobalValues ) {
            if( object != null && object instanceof GlobalValues.ValueKey ) {
                switch( ( (GlobalValues.ValueKey)object ).getKey() ) {
                case NONE:
                    // General Notification
                    break;
                case SEEME:
                    doTryMe( GlobalValues.getInstance().getSeeMe() );
                    break;
                case OTHERVALUE:
                    // do something else
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note that it also implements a global singleton pattern through `getInstance()`, and a way to identify which value has changed through the `enum` and wrapper class.

Comment: I feel silly saying, but after looking at the links attached to your answer. I just can't quite get my head around your solution. Could you please either explain it further

Comment: I added a skeleton implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register observer on variables in java - this is just not possible. I would work on methods - just create setter and getter for your global variable. There are two possibilities:

- using JDK Proxies: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076233/java-se/explore-the-dynamic-proxy-api.html
- AspecjJ

You will have to generate proxy for each class that you need to "monitor". This proxy-monitor can have only one implementation, and you can register it on multiple classes. For example, in case of JDK proxy you would implement method `invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)` , and all methods calls on the proxied class will go trough invoke(....).

Such solution have one big advantage: classes that you are monitoring are not coupled to monitoring framework